# Why isn't my text changing color? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

Trying to change the color of the text with javascript - here is what I have

```
<input name="text" value="black" id="black" type="radio" onclick="changetextcolor(this);">"Black"
<input name="text" value="purple" id="purple" type="radio" onclick="changetextcolor(this);">"Purple"
<input name="text" value="lightpink" id="lightpink" type="radio" onclick="changetextcolor(this);">"Light Pink"
function changetextcolor(element){
    document.body.style.Color = element.value;
};
```

here is the web page I am working on http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mariaroo/validation.html

Comment: Advice for the future — learn to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onclick="someFunction"`

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `color` property in lowercase and not with capital letters.

`color` and not `Color`.

```js
 function changetextcolor(element){
   console.log(element.value);
      document.body.style.color = element.value;
 };
```

```html
<input name="text" value="black" id="black" type="radio" onclick="changetextcolor(this);">Black
<input name="text" value="Purple" id="purple" type="radio" onclick="changetextcolor(this);">Purple
<input name="text" value="lightpink" id="lightpink" type="radio" onclick="changetextcolor(this);">Light Pink
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the wrong property in your code. It should be `document.body.style.color` (note all lowercase `color`).

Answer (score 1):

You mixed something up.
You can not use a .text property for styling the color of your text.

Try .color instead. This should work.

```
function changetextcolor(element){
  document.body.style.color = element.value;
};
```